# What does the AWS CloudWatch metric RequestCount mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monitoring, amazon-elb, cloudwatch

I'm trying to figure out the meaning of the AWS CloudWatch metric RequestCount. The only [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_MonitoringLoadBalancerWithCW.html) I can find says *The number of requests handled by the load balancer*, which is remarkably unhelpful:

- Is this a total count or some sort of rate? The graphs don't show a monotonically increasing total value, which makes me doubt it is a total.
- Over what time period is this count/rate? Does it reset periodically?
- Why isn't the internet filled with people asking this question?

Answer (score 5):

1. It will report a sum of all requests over the reporting period selected. If 1 min is selected, then you will get requests per minute.
2. This is selectable. Between 1 min and 1 day.

Comment: Is it a rolling aggregate or does it reset at boundaries?

Comment: Resets at boundaries. None of the cloudwatch stats are rolling aggregates. If you wanted that, you could use the api to get stats and add up the results yourself.